# Batchable Interface finish method and sending email from managed package

Tags: email, managed-package, batch

We are using the Database.Batchable interface.
 In the finish method, we want to send a mail to the user who started the job like this: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    // Get the ID of the AsyncApexJob representing this batch job
    // from Database.BatchableContext.
    // Query the AsyncApexJob object to retrieve the current job's information.
    AsyncApexJob a = [SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed,
       TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
       FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id =
       :BC.getJobId()];
    // Send an email to the Apex job's submitter notifying of job completion.
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {a.CreatedBy.Email};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setSubject('Apex Sharing Recalculation ' + a.Status);
    mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch Apex job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems +
     ' batches with '+ a.NumberOfErrors + ' failures.');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

On the same page section "Batch Apex Best Practices" it says:

> When a batch Apex job is run, email notifications are sent to the user who submitted the batch job. If the code is included in a managed package and the subscribing org is running the batch job, notifications are sent to the recipient listed in the Apex Exception Notification Recipient field.

Because of this point, I am a little bit confused. Will the email be sent to the user who started the batch job even though our code resides in a managed package?

Comment: Minor note: you should be using setTargetObjectId instead of setToAddresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email notification you've quoted is for when exceptions occur, and have nothing to do with your code. Using setTargetObjectId to use UserInfo.getUserId() is sufficient to notify the user that submitted the batch job.